# Do action on user closing tab or windows

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this code which works with jQuery, I can do many operation when user close tab or windows.

Code is working in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Are there a way to do it in AngularJs?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var validNavigation = false;

     function wireUpEvents() {
         var dont_confirm_leave = 0; //set dont_confirm_leave to 1 when you want the  user to be able to leave withou confirmation
         var leave_message = ' ';
         function quitWdindow(e) {
             if (!validNavigation) {
                 return leave_message;

             }
         }
         window.onbeforeunload=quitWdindow;

         // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
         $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 116){
           validNavigation = true;
         }
         });

         // Attach the event click for all links in the page
         $("a").bind("click", function() {
         validNavigation = true;
          });
          // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
          $("form").bind("submit", function() {
          validNavigation = true;
         });

         // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
         $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
         validNavigation = true;
         });

     }

     // Wire up the events as soon as the DOM tree is ready
     $(document).ready(function() {
       wireUpEvents();
     });
</script>
```

Edit

I tried

```
angular.module('My.App').controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($log, $state, $AppAuthenticationService, $CoreWindowService, $AppConfiguration, $filter, $window){
    var vm = this;

    ...
    ...
    $window.bind('unload', function(){
        alert("unload");
    }
}
```

but get error

Answer (score 0):

You need `window.onunload` event, that is triggered. [Documentation on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)

```
window.onunload = function(){
  alert('Are you sure?');
}
```

In AngularJS you can use $window service:

```
//inject $window into controller
controller('test', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
  $window.bind('unload', function(){
    //do stuff
  }
}])
```